# How do I track daily code metrics on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, metrics, code-metrics

I am looking for any extension on visual studio code for tracking how many lines I have written by day, maybe export this information to a file.

Could you know something able to do it?

Comment: This is not a 'general computing' question at all, as one close voter decided for some reason. It *is*, however, off-topic, since it is asking for tool recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [WakaTime](https://wakatime.com/vs-code) plugin. WakaTime is also compatible with other editors. Therefore, the use of WakaTime is more preferable. Other alternatives for Visual Studio Code to keep track of code metrics include:

- [Time Master](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iceworks-team.iceworks-time-master)
- [Code Time](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=softwaredotcom.swdc-vscode)
- [TimeWalk-VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=desmondlzy.timewalk-vscode)

Comment: perfect, do you know if it gets a long time for synchronizing de collected data to the server?? I have installed and pushed the API Key, but the data was not synchronized yet.

Comment: I've been using WakaTime in the past with a repo on GitHub. I was only getting the WakaTime metrics automatically at the end of the day using a workflow. The WakaTime plugin is most likely running in real time locally. However, the transmission of data to the server side may not be real-time. Therefore, you may have to wait for the end of the day.

Comment: I tested it now. The Wakatime plugin syncs my recent code editing actions from Visual Studio Code by posting them to the Wakatime Dashboard. [Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irun7.png)